# Http_tiny in rust 1.7 not serving index.html *.js, *.css and images from static page

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, rust, localhost

guys, my open-http server from node js is falling with package pkg creating exe. I tried to use http_tiny in rust 1.7 but cant run the server. Im on basic rust gnu stack on windows 10. Do you have any ideas how to use http_tiny to start exe then open browser and serve folder ./src2/index.html with all *.js *.css and *.png and *.jpg? I mean creating static server with static web page IN RUST?

```
npm init

create index.js with init
npm install http-server
npm install pkg
npm install cli

to package json:
scripts{
"start": "http-server -o ./src"
},
 "bin" : "./bin/my-bin.js",

and to my-bin.js:

#!/usr/bin/env node
var join = require('path').join
var childProcess = require('child_process');
var args = process.argv.slice(2);

 args.unshift(__dirname + '/../'); 

childProcess.exec('npm start', (err, stdout) => {
if (err) console.log(err);
console.log(stdout);
})

command for exe:
pkg -t win .
```

NOT WORKING,TRYING RUST ^^^
My Rust attempt with refused npm from the store:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Please do not post text (code, errors) as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: This needs more focus. Do you want a solution to your `open-http` problem? or your `tiny-http` problem? I understand either would do for your purposes, but StackOverflow requires questions to be targeted at a single problem at a time.

Comment: As far as the Rust related concerns, if you import your desired `Method` with `use tiny_http::Method`, does that fix the issue? If not, what error messages do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Now I know what the problem is: I use pkg package from node js, then I use NSIS3 to create installer from *.zip, the program is during installation  unpacked to Program Files, then icon launcher is installed to Windows10 and this is the problem of pkg it is not well resolving paths, coz every html5 file of http server uses relative paths and pkg is resolving absolute path of icon launcher and can not read index.html relatively in local folder src/index.html coz really it is IconLaunch/src/index.html and app falls down. I have thousands of paths relatively defined so Im not gonna put it to MS store, I better let it be in local folder for people to use for free here: https://uloz.to/file/PRr28QEVvrMD/autoskola-free-2023-windows10-zip
[image: Running program Autoskola Free with pkg node js locally in folder run]